# How to find corresponding column in differnt data frames

Tags: r

```
emp <- data.frame(
hi_ras1_55 = c(1:5), 
kk.ras2_ml= c(6:10),
ii_ras4.kj = c(11:15)) 

 pp <- data.frame(
emp_id = c (1:5), 
emp_name = c("Rick","Dan","Michelle","Ryan","Gary"),
salary = c("ras1","ras2","ras3","ras3","ras4")) 

dat <- data.frame(
gg = c(21:25), 
Rick= c(6:10))
```

I want to read dat and then extract the name of the second column "Rick" and then extract what corresponds to it under the column salary in pp "ras1" and then find the column in emp that contains this name "hi_ras1_55" and put the column in dat with a title "final".

desired output:

```
 gg Rick    final
 21    6      1
 22    7      2
 23    8       3
 24    9       4
 25   10       5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find the `salary` entry using the column name:

```r
salary = pp[pp["emp_name"] == names(dat)[2], "salary"]
```

Now use it to add the column that includes this string to `dat` using `cbind`:

```r
dat <- cbind(dat, final = emp[, grepl(salary, names(emp))])
```

Function `grepl` was used to test whether column name contains `salary`.

Answer (score 1):

I am a create a function person if you need to consistently do this over and over, which it seems like one might want to do from the sample:

```
 extractor<-function(dat, pp, emp){
 # get the employee name save it to variable
  gent=colnames(dat)[2]

 #use variable to select the salary class
 salary<-pp%>%
    filter(emp_name==agent)%>%
    select(salary)%>%
    pull()
#create output values from the emp dataframe
  output<-emp%>%
    select(contains(salary))

#bind the output to the original data this can be piped from above
#but the order of the variables will not be as you indicated  
  output<-cbind(dat, output)
  return(output)
}
extrator(dat,pp, emp)
```

[image]
extractor(dat,pp, emp)